# cards bootstrap 4.1 not working in Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, bootstrap-4

My cards are stretching too much down in Internet Explorer. I have used Bootsrap 4.1

How can I fix this up?

open [this](http://monishussain.online.cp-in-17.bigrockservers.com/) link in IE and check Work section of this portfolio.

Comment: You need to use `h-100` for image link. For ex. `<a class="h-100" href="img/glozzom.png" data-toggle="lightbox"><img src="img/glozzom.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>` & then check it.

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** because you didn't provide the relevant part of your webpage that causes this unexpected result.

Comment: Sir It has worked but now it is showing too much of spaces between the cards and link of view is also not working...

Comment: Duplicate of [My bootstrap cards are stretching too much down in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51228057/my-bootstrap-cards-are-stretching-too-much-down-in-internet-explorer)