# My bootstrap cards are stretching too much down in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, bootstrap-4

I have used Bootsrap 4.1  How can I fix this up?  open this link in IE and check Work section of this portfolio Visit http://monishussain.online.cp-in-17.bigrockservers.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `card` class from the div shown in the image below and add `border` class to it to give it a 1px border.

[Full resolution image](https://ibb.co/dBZ448)

Change your button code from

```
<button class="btn btn-warning d-md-none d-lg-block"><a href="Blog Admin panel/index.html" class="text-dark" target="_blank">View</a></button>
```

to

```
<a class="btn btn-warning d-md-none d-lg-block" href="glozzom2/index.html">View</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mam...In this my View anchor tag is also not working can you fix it up...??

Comment: What do you mean by not working and where is it not working ?

Comment: Please accept this answer, if it works for you . Thanks :)

Comment: Thank You....From where I can Accept your answer,Actually i m new to stackoverflow

Comment: Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. its just below the upvote/downvote button